# Google Lighthouse Command Not Found in macOS Terminal

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm-install, lighthouse

I'm running macOS Mojave, and I've tried installing the [Google Lighthouse package for Node.JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse) using the NPM package manager using the following `npm install` command with the `-g` option to install the package globally:

```sh
npm install lighthouse -g
```

But no matter what I do I get the `-bash: lighthouse: command not found` error indicating that the command is not recognized by macOS, or perhaps it didn't export correctly. I even tried `source ~/.bash_profile`, but it didn't help.

I even tried to uninstall Lighthouse with `npm remove lighthouse -g` and ran the following to remove the cache for NPM:

```sh
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
```

I then reinstalled with `npm install lighthouse -g` and it still says that the command isn't found. I even tried closing all my terminal windows, but the command is still not found.

When I execute the `node --version` command it returns: `v12.16.1`, and `npm -v` returns `6.13.4`. Is the `lighthouse` command not compatible with v12 of Node.js?

I'm at my wits end. Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Do I need to export the path for the package or something? Did I miss something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just running v12 of Node.js in Docker container and installed Lighthouse in there and got it to work.

I used `"lighthouse": "^5.6.0"` in my `package.json` file's dependencies, and then did `npm install` before starting the container.

Once the container was running I did a `docker ps` to get the container ID, and then I did the `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash` command to enter the container, and the `lighthouse` command finally worked in there.

Answer (score 2):

install lighthouse after this command

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm exec lighthouse` - that worked for me.